# JavaScript and Facebook pixel

Tags: javascript, facebook, variables

I was wondering if this script would work?

I have to implement this facebook script on 15 pages and replaced the FacebookId variable in 2 places - in window._fbq.push() and in the URL. Thanks

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
            if(window.location.pathname == '/test') {
            FacebookId = '123123123';
            }
            if(window.location.pathname == '/test2') {
            FacebookId = '34534534534';
            }

            <script>(function() {
            var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
            if (!_fbq.loaded) {
            var fbds = document.createElement('script');
            fbds.async = true;
            fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
            _fbq.loaded = true;
            }
            })();
            window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
            window._fbq.push(['track', FacebookId , {'value':'0.01','currency':'USD'}]);
            </script>
            <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev="+FacebookId+"&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>

            }
            </script>
```

Comment: 1) wrong syntax, you have script tags all over the place 2) how would noscript work with a scripted var inside it? The first part would work - you likely need to do `if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("/test/") !=-1)` but the pixel will not work. Set it on the server instead

Comment: So basically I have to duplicate the noscript for each page?

Would you post a code that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the JavaScript part. The noscript part will NOT work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = window.location.pathname, FacebookId="";
if(path.indexOf('/test/') !=-1) {
  FacebookId = '123123123';
}
if(path.indexOf('/test2/') !=-1) {
  FacebookId = '34534534534';
}
(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', FacebookId , {'value':'0.01','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
```

---

Here is one if you could vary the noscript content

```
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" 
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=12121212121&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>

<script>
    window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
    var fb = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0].innerHTML.split("?ev=")[1].split("&amp")[0];
    window._fbq.push(['track',fb, {'value':'0.01','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
```

Comment: I only have access a "footer" field - We are using Netsuite and what is inserted on 1 page will be on all pages that is why i need to use window.location.pathname - No PHP available...I wish... :)

Comment: It seems that the script is not firing up, i do not know why, maybe i need to use location.href